# How to update the list when I click the button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have the below code for fetching updated data on changing the filter value and pressing update. The data is getting fetched, but the list is not getting updated. How to make this work. The list is showing properly once loaded but it is not updating.

```
child: ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.red,
  ),
  onPressed: () async {
    setState(() {
      accordianFlag = false;
    });
    // programsListFuture = getCropNutritionPrograms();
    // var updatedProgramsList = await getCropNutritionPrograms();
    // setState(() {
    //   programsListFuture = Future.value(updatedProgramsList);
    // });
    fetchData();  // <--- not working. I tried various other method, but list is not updating
  },
  child: Text(
    'Update',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
    ),
  ),
)
```

Full code:

```
class CropNutritionProgramOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  CropNutritionProgramOverviewScreen({Key? key, required this.showAppbar, required this.showBottombar}) : super(key: key);
  bool showAppbar = false;
  bool showBottombar = false;

  @override
  State<CropNutritionProgramOverviewScreen> createState() => _CropNutritionProgramOverviewScreenState();
}

class _CropNutritionProgramOverviewScreenState extends State<CropNutritionProgramOverviewScreen> {
  Future<RegionsList?>? regionsListFuture;
  Future<CropsModel?>? cropsListFuture;
  Future<CropNutritionProgramModel?>? programsListFuture;
  bool accordianFlag = false;
  bool _showContent = false;
  String regionSelected = '1';
  String cropSelected = '0';
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> regionDropdownItems = [];
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> cropDropdownItems = [];

  _CropNutritionProgramOverviewScreenState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<RegionsList?> getRegions() async {
    RegionsList regionsList = await getRegionsAPI();
    print("flutter - regions list: " + regionsList.toString());
    
    List<Region> regions = regionsList.regions ?? [];
    for (Region region in regions) {
      regionDropdownItems.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(region.name),
        value: region.id.toString(),
      ));
    }
    if (regions.length > 0) {
      regionSelected = regions[0].id.toString();
    }

    return regionsList;
  }

  Future<CropsModel?> getCrops(int regionId) async {
    CropsModel cropsList = await getCropsAPI(regionId);
    print("flutter - cropsList: " + cropsList.toString());

    List<Crop> crops = cropsList.cropsList ?? [];
    for (Crop crop in crops) {
      cropDropdownItems.add(DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Text(crop.name),
        value: crop.id.toString(),
      ));
    }

    return cropsList;
  }

  Future<CropNutritionProgramModel?> getCropNutritionPrograms() async {
    var regionId = int.parse(regionSelected);
    var cropId = int.parse(cropSelected);
    CropNutritionProgramModel programsModel = await getCropNutritionProgramsAPI(regionId, cropId);
    print("flutter - cropNutritionProgramsModel: " + programsModel.toString());
    return programsModel;
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchData() async {
    return await Future.wait([getRegions(), getCrops(0), getCropNutritionPrograms()]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: widget.showAppbar ? TopAppBar() : null,
      drawer: widget.showAppbar ? TopDrawer() : null,
      body: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        future: fetchData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return _buildLoadingIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var regionsList = snapshot.data?.elementAt(0) as RegionsList?;
            var cropsList = snapshot.data?.elementAt(1) as CropsModel?;
            var programsList = snapshot.data?.elementAt(2) as CropNutritionProgramModel?;
            List<Region> regions = regionsList == null ? [] : regionsList!.regions;
            List<Crop> crops = cropsList == null ? [] : cropsList!.cropsList;
            List<CropNutritionProgram> programs = programsList == null ? [] : programsList.cropNutritionPrograms;
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 8),
                    child: Text(
                      'Crop Nutrition Programs',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                            Image.asset(
                              regionsAssetPath,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                            Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Discover Crop Nutrition Program recommendations for your state!",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 8.0),
                              child: StatefulBuilder(
                                builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                                  return Card(
                                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      side: new BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          height: 40,
                                          child: Transform.translate(
                                            offset: Offset(0, -8),
                                            child: ListTile(
                                              title: const Text("Filter By", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16, color: Colors.red)),
                                              leading: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined, color: Colors.red,),
                                              trailing: IconButton(
                                                icon: Icon(
                                                  _showContent ? Icons.arrow_drop_up : Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.red,),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    _showContent = !_showContent;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              ),
                                              onTap: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _showContent = !_showContent;
                                                });
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                            border: new Border(bottom: new BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        _showContent
                                        ? Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
                                            child: Column(
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                              children: [
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 5,
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: GlobalMargin.leftAccordian, right: GlobalMargin.rightAccordian),
                                                  child: InputDecorator(
                                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 0),
                                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                    ),
                                                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                                        value: regionSelected,
                                                        isExpanded: true,
                                                        isDense: true,
                                                        hint: Text('Select Region'),
                                                        icon:
                                                        const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined),
                                                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            accordianFlag = true;
                                                            if (value != null) {
                                                              regionSelected = value;
                                                            }
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        items: regionDropdownItems
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 10,
                                                ),
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: GlobalMargin.leftAccordian, right: GlobalMargin.rightAccordian),
                                                  child: InputDecorator(
                                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 0),
                                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                    ),
                                                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                                        value: cropSelected,
                                                        isExpanded: true,
                                                        isDense: true,
                                                        hint: Text('Select Crop'),
                                                        icon:
                                                        const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_outlined),
                                                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            accordianFlag = true;
                                                            if (value != null) {
                                                              cropSelected = value;
                                                            }
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        items: cropDropdownItems,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height: 10,
                                                ),
                                                Container(
                                                  width: double.infinity,
                                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    width: 200,
                                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                        primary: Colors.red,
                                                      ),
                                                      onPressed: () async {
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          accordianFlag = false;
                                                        });
                                                        // programsListFuture = getCropNutritionPrograms();
                                                        // var updatedProgramsList = await getCropNutritionPrograms();
                                                        // setState(() {
                                                        //   programsListFuture = Future.value(updatedProgramsList);
                                                        // });
                                                        fetchData();
                                                      },
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        'Update',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    )
                                                  )
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        : Container(),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            ListView.separated(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemCount: programs.length,
                              separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(height: 1),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(-8, 8, 0, 8),
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title: Text("${programs[index].name}"),
                                    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.red),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print("crop nutrition program tapped");
                                      navigateToCropNutritionListScreen(context, int.parse(regionSelected), 0);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            ),
                          ]
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),  
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Text('No data available');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void navigateToCropNutritionListScreen(BuildContext context, int regionId, int stateId) {
    var provider = Provider.of<AppBarContitonProvider>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    );
    provider.setInnerPageLoaded(true);
    provider.setPdfScreenLoaded(false, '');
    NavKey.key.currentState?.pushNamed(Routes.cropNutritionList, 
      arguments: CropNutritionListArguments(regionId, stateId)).then((value) {
    });
  }

  Widget _buildLoadingIndicator() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

I have updated the code to use only one future variable but still the list is not rebuilding when new data is fetched.
**Code**: https://pastebin.com/AYENDAkr

Could you please help me with this? Thanks.

---

I am new to flutter. I don't understand why when a variable changes the corresponding widget does not update.

```
programsListFuture = getCropNutritionPrograms();
var updatedProgramsList = await getCropNutritionPrograms();
  setState(() {
    programsListFuture = Future.value(updatedProgramsList);
});
```

The future is assigned new value, but why is the list not updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continuously monitor the changes of a certain attribute, you can use `ValueListenableBuilder` and `ValueNotifier` to achieve that.

[ValueListenableBuilder DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1)

You can run this DartPad to see the effect.

I use ValueListenableBuilder to listen to the datasource. If the datasource changes, it will re-execute the build.

You can copy and run this code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const ValueListenableDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class ValueListenableDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ValueListenableDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<ValueListenableDemo> createState() => _ValueListenableDemoState();
}

class _ValueListenableDemoState extends State<ValueListenableDemo> {
  ValueNotifier<List<int>> datasource = ValueNotifier<List<int>>([1, 2, 3]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Click the refresh button in the bottom right corner to update the list.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<int>>(
                valueListenable: datasource,
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: value.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('Item ${value[index]}'),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            int count = Random().nextInt(10) + 1;

            datasource.value = List<int>.generate(count, (index) => index);
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the value listener builder. I will try that. The dart pad linked however does not show this. Can you please check again?

Comment: @JohnDoe In dartpad, I used ValueListenableBuilder to listen to ValueNotifier(datasource). I have updated the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try and reorganize the way you initialize the app, using the future builder like this and creating the future in itself is an error, start by working this out before moving to your described bug, see the flutter youtube channel on this take  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEdw_1B7JHY

```
 //Dont to 
 FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
 future: fetchData(),
```

Comment: With only one API method, I can use future like shown in the video. But how to do when there are multiple API calls?

Comment: I have tried as you suggested, but still the list is not reloading. https://pastebin.com/AYENDAkr Any idea why?